# Turn key-less array to associative array

Tags: php

The following code outputs `would` where we expect it to output `12/5/10`. The reason is `array_search` only works on associative arrays and `explode` returns a key-less array, so `$k` is `false` and `$k+1` is `1`.

```
$s = 'We would like to book a double room form 12/5/10 for three nights.';
$s_arr = explode(' ', $s);
$k = array_search('from', $s_arr);
$from = $s_arr[$k+1];
echo $from;
```

We can verify this by using a literal definition like this

```
$s_arr = array(
  0 => 'We',
  1 => 'would',
  2 => 'like',
  3 => 'to',
  4 => 'book',
  5 => 'a',
  6 => 'double',
  7 => 'room',
  8 => 'form',
  9 => '12/5/10',
  10=> 'for',
  11=> 'three',
  12=> 'nights.');
$k = array_search('from', $s_arr);
$from = $s_arr[$k+1];
echo $from;
```

This time the correct value is out which is `12/5/10`.

Is there a way to turn a key-less array to an associative one?

Comment: Just tried the second code block, it fails too! What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you doing this at all? It seems the purpose of this function is to extract the date. If so, it would make sense to use a regular expression. preg_match is way faster for these things than your array explode roundtrip and array_search.

Comment: @mario - these are beginning steps to implement an intelligent responder. A lot will be changed, but for now explode+search would do.

Comment: You know, that's a difficult undertaking! ;] Natural language parsers/responders aren't easy. But especially since you've already run into one misspelling, you should take the regex route. It's way more reliable and shorter. preg_match("#[from]{2,6}\s*(\d+/\d+/\d+)#", $s, $match) for catching your date. Works for misspellings like frm, fromm, form, frrom, etc.. Easier. Come over to the dark side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say it does this because you misspelled "from" in the original string you are exploding.

Comment: Just tested this code with the spelling corrected, and it works fine.

Comment: @Majid - I recommend using Netbeans or some other IDE - that should make it easier to identify typos like this.  Also, set error logging to include E_NOTICE and keep an eye on the error log ( http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php )